# Moderator Support: Merge launchpad and askubuntu account

Tags: support, moderators

I would like to merge my [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~cheddiemerai/) and my [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/271219/cheddiemerai) accounts. Can I receive some assistance from a moderator? Thank you

Comment: Umm.. what? We don't have any power on Launchpad. Do you mean you accidentally created two Ask Ubuntu accounts, one with your Launchpad ID and one with whatever ID this account is using?

Comment: Go to your user profile, there will be a link called "my logins". Click on it, and add a login using Launchpad OpenID.

Comment: @muru thank you it worked.

Comment: @Seth I might have phrased it wrong, however, I only asked I know it could be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your user profile, there will be a link called "my logins". Click on it, and add a login using Launchpad OpenID.

Or go to: https://askubuntu.com/users/login-add while you are logged in.